# How do I change the maximum number of ticks on a graph in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a lab report due tomorrow and I am supposed to plot a data set given to me by the professor. The biology laboratory guidelines tell me to have no more than **5 tick marks** on the graphs vertical axis. However the data plot, when I auto-create graph in Excel, is making a vertical axis with 8 ticks. How do I change the maximum number of ticks on the graph?

Note: I have tried changing the scale of the graph but that has left me with the same problem of too many major ticks on the graph.

I am a fairly inexperienced Excel user so any help as quickly as possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many rows/columns of data do you have?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the axis whose tick
   marks you want to change. Excel
   displays a Context menu for the
   axis.
2. Choose `Format Axis` from the Context
   menu. (If there is no `Format Axis`
   choice, then you did not right-click
   on an axis in step 1). Excel
   displays the `Format Axis` dialog box.
3. Make sure the `Axis Options` tab is
   selected.
4. To the right of `Major Unit`, click
   `Fixed` and specify a multiple at
   which you want the major tick marks
   to appear. (for instance 2)
5. To the right of `Minor Unit`, click
   `Fixed` and specify a multiple at
   which you want the minor tick marks
   to appear. (This step is optional)
6. Click on OK.

Comment: Alas, as of 2018, this no longer works, because of changes in the UI.  There's no "Major Unit" in my "Format Axis>Axis Options". :-(